# Is it possible to do unnecessary testing for numbers?

Tags: unit-testing, language-agnostic

For example, if I wanted to test that number `x = 5`, I could write a test to test that indeed, `x` equals `5`. Would it then be necessary to add additional tests such as `x != 4` and `x != 6`? Or does the fact that checking for `x = 5` imply that those other tests are true too?

Comment: Can you describe In what context the testing occurs?

Comment: A simple unit test. E.g: If I have a starting value of 100, and call "foo" which minuses a number from 100. So if I call foo(20), I should expect 80 as the result. Would it be neccessary for me to test that the result of foo(20) would NOT be equal to 79 and 81?

Comment: No, it would not be necessary!

Answer (score 0):

If the variable `x` exactly represents the number, it is not neccessary to test against different values. Aside from being obvious, this follows from the transitivity of the equality operator which is assumed in standard mathematics.

However, many fractional numbers like 0.1 cannot be exactly represented by standard binary encodings. In this case, you have to accept a certain error and therefore shouldn't test for `x == 0.1` because it can be `false` even if the two values are equal within the required tolerance. Instead you should test if `x <= 0.1 + e AND x >= 0.1 - e` where `e` is the accepted error.

By the way, I used `==` instead of `=` for the equality operator because in C and related languages, `x = 5` is always true, no matter what the original value of `x` is :).

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the context and the paradigm.

By example, in object-oriented programming languages, you can define equality for a type/class and that sometimes means equality is no longer transitive. It would be possible that both `x == 5` and `x == 6` are true. Worst it could even be that `x == 6` but `x` is not `6`.